# Does "underappreciated" have a "woe is me" connotation?

Tags: connotation

I'm editing a grant and I just came across the word 'underappreciated'. It's being used in the context of saying 'The thing that we are proposing to study is underappreciated.' Whenever I hear or see the word 'underappreciated' I always think of poor, depressed Eeyore from Winnie the Pooh or Baby sitting in the corner at the end of Dirty Dancing... Is that just me? Could it ever be a synonym for 'not well studied'?

Comment: It's a neutral term. I've seen it used by writers when they want to give attention to something good that has been passed over for some reason or another. For example, while a band's third album may be popular, their debut may be underappreciated.

Comment: Please include your basic research of the term.  A dictionary reference might help you answer this.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to being not well studied, the word definitely suggests that there is something to appreciate which is not currently appreciated. I do not think it suggests "mopey" as I do not believe areas of research have feelings that can be hurt (although researchers do.)

On its own, it could be interpreted as reflecting purely subjective aesthetic judgements on the author's part. If the author uses this word, they should seek to firmly justify and defend the potential importance of the area, the unrecognized (under-appreciated) benefits of studying it, and the potential (under-appreciated) costs and harms of letting it go unstudied.

Comment: Yes, in addition to the *purely subjective aesthetic*, there is the problem of selling the grant request by using a negative about both the study subject and *poor me*. No one wins friends (or friends with money) by saying "You don't appreciate this and you don't appreciate that." Might as well call 'em all poopyheads.